# preg_match_all returns empty array

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

$matches returns an empty array...

this doesn't work

```
$missedvalue = $_GET['missedvalue'];
$pattern = "/(?:\"(?:\\\\\"|[^\"])+\")/is";
preg_match_all($pattern, $missedvalue, $matches);
```

but this works

```
$missedvalue = 'test "gift card"';
$pattern = "/(?:\"(?:\\\\\"|[^\"])+\")/is";
preg_match_all($pattern, $missedvalue, $matches);
```

Whats the deal? I can't quit put my finger on it... i've trying casting `$missedvalue` as `(string)` but that didn't work. I'm at a loss. oh and `$_GET['missedvalue']` definitely equals `test "gift card"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use single quote in pattern like this:

```
$pattern = '/(?:"(?:\\\"|[^"])+")/i';
```

Comment: Because I stumble through regex and always just have to use what I can find.. however using ur regex still didn't help.

Comment: `string 'test &quot;gift card&quot;' (length=26)`

Comment: Yup that's what I suspected that you don't have `"` in your query parameter at first place :P Great that your problem could be solved.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried your code on my machine and it works for me. Maybe you're doing something to $pattern or some pre-processing happening to the header before you run the regexp... ?

Comment: I just tried this `str_replace('"', '=', $_REQUEST['missedvalue'])` and it doesn't remove the double quotes.. hmmmm